# resize options graphicsmagick

Tags: image, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to resize an image with graphicsmagick.

I need it to fit a specific width&height. However, with the following command: `-resize 400x200` it resizes **until** the image has reached either one of the width or height properties, while I need it to 'zoom' a bit until it fits both.

Are there any options available to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Append "!" to the geometry.  This will force a resize to exactly the specified dimensions, without necessarily maintaining the aspect ratio.

So:

```
gm convert input -resize 400x200! output
```

or, if your shell does something peculiar with the "!",

```
gm convert input -resize "400x200!" output
```